# Strange Grails behaviour populating List at bootstrap

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm becoming crazy on a strange Grails behaviour.

I get a domain class user :

```
class User {

    String firstName
    String token
    List roles = [] as List

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I modify my BootStrap.groovy like this to populate 5 user instance :

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        switch (Environment.getCurrent()) {
            case 'DEVELOPMENT':
                def user1 = new User(
                    id: 1,
                    firstName: 'Enricot',
                    token: 'L\'abricot'
                )
                user1.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
                user1.save(failOnError: true)
                def user2 = new User(
                    id: 2,
                    firstName: 'Arnaud',
                    token: 'Dauphin')
                user2.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
                user2.roles.add('PERM_WRITE')
                user2.save(failOnError: true)
                def user3 = new User(
                    id: 3,
                    firstName: 'Magalie',
                    token: 'La banane')
                user3.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
                user3.roles.add('PERM_READ')
                user3.save(failOnError: true)
                def user4 = new User(
                    id: 4,
                    firstName: 'Jeremy',
                    token: 'Wistiti')
                user4.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
                user4.roles.add('ROLE_ADMIN')
                user4.save(failOnError: true)
                def user5 = new User(
                    id: 5,
                    firstName: 'Jimini',
                    token: 'Criquet')
                user5.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
                user5.roles.add('ROLE_INTERACTIONS')
                user5.save(failOnError: true)
                break
            case "test":
                DataBuilder.init()
                break
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

In my controller, when I'm getting one user, all fields are corect, except the List.

If I do :

```
def user = User.get(1)
println user.firstName // Output is "Enricot"
println user.token // Output is "L'abricot"
println user.roles // Output is "[]" and not "[ROLE_USER]"
```

Trying populate object like this did not solve my problem :

```
def user1 = new User(
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Enricot',
        token: 'L\'abricot',
        roles: ['ROLE_USER']).save(failOnError: true)
```

I'have try with double quote, simple quote.

The most funny part is when I'm making "user.roles" INTO BootStrap.groovy, I get the correct List.

It's making no sense for me, any help is welcome,

Comment: As an FYI, you don't have to do the environments that way.  Just do environments { development { } test { } production { } }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not strange behavior, you're doing it wrong :)

When you add a field that you want to be persistent, you need to give Grails information about how to store it. Just a simple `List` isn't enough information. If it's a list of other domain classes, it will create a foreign key and store the ids. If it's a list of Strings, it will store them as varchars. As shown [in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes), you need to do something like this:

```
class User {
   String firstName
   String token
   static hasMany = [roles: String]
}
```

This changes the backing collection to a `Set`, but this is likely correct for roles since you don't care about ordering and want uniqueness. If you do need ordering, add an uninitialized `List` field to signal to Grails that you don't want a `Set`:

```
class User {
   String firstName
   String token
   List roles
   static hasMany = [roles: String]
}
```

This changes how you populate the data. Instead of directly adding to the collection, use the dynamic `addToRoles` method that gets added for you:

```
class BootStrap {
   def init = { ctx ->
      environments {
         development {
            def user1 = new User(firstName: 'Enricot', token: 'L\'abricot')
            user1.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
            user1.save(failOnError: true)
            def user2 = new User(firstName: 'Arnaud', token: 'Dauphin')
            user2.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
            user2.addToRoles('PERM_WRITE')
            user2.save(failOnError: true)
            def user3 = new User(firstName: 'Magalie', token: 'La banane')
            user3.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
            user3.addToRoles('PERM_READ')
            user3.save(failOnError: true)
            def user4 = new User(firstName: 'Jeremy', token: 'Wistiti')
            user4.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
            user4.addToRoles('ROLE_ADMIN')
            user4.save(failOnError: true)
            def user5 = new User(firstName: 'Jimini', token: 'Criquet')
            user5.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
            user5.addToRoles('ROLE_INTERACTIONS')
            user5.save(failOnError: true)
         }
         test {
            DataBuilder.init()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments for information about the environment block support in BootStrap.groovy.

Also note that I removed your explicit id values since you are not using assigned ids, so those values are ignored.

Finally, it looks like you're rolling your own security. Don't do this. Use a proven framework. Both [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [Shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) are powerful and easy to get started with.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal behaviour for grails. The code below just adds item to list in current object (**Important!** not to database reference):

```
user1.roles.add('ROLE_USER')
```

To add to database mapping to roles use dynamic method like this:

```
user1.addToRoles('ROLE_USER')
```

Assumption: you mean for your domain

```
List<Strings> roles 
static hasMany = [roles:String]
```